# Cronjob not being executed

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to run `rsync-books` with a crontab. Typing `crontab -e` outputs:

```
55 12 * * * diegoaguilar /storage/bin/rsync-books
```

Where `/storage/bin/rsync-books` looks like this:

```
if [ -d "/media/Beagle/books" ]; then
  rsync -rP --delete --verbose /storage/Copy/Books/ /media/Beagle/books >> ~/rsync-books.log
fi
```

Just to confirm, this script has got executable permissions.
I tried waiting at that time the command, when /media/Beagle/books existed and it neither rsync anyhing or the log file was created.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: do you run `crontab -e` as user `diegoaguilar`?

Comment: Yep @blissini I did

Comment: so there is no need to specify the user.
What happens if you create the entry:
`* * * * * touch /home/diegoaguilar/testfile`,
Does testfile get created in your home directory?

Comment: `crontab -e` and remove 'diegoaguilar'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron runs commands without an environment so there's no `PATH` variable set.  Because of this you need to specify the full path to `rsync` in your script.

```
if [ -d "/media/Beagle/books" ]; then
  /usr/bin/rsync -rP --delete --verbose /storage/Copy/Books/ /media/Beagle/books >> ~/rsync-books.log
fi
```

Also, if you're running `crontab -e` don't include the username in the crontab entry.  Your crontab should look like

`55 12 * * * /storage/bin/rsync-books`

EDIT: cron runs in a non-interactive shell so the environment (and PATH) may be different from what you expect.  It's always best to specify full paths in any script that will be run from cron.

Comment: not true on my test system (Debian 8.2).

Comment: @blissini What's not true?  Does cron run with an environment or is `rsync` not located at `/usr/bin/rsync`?

Comment: my cron entry:
`* * * * * touch /home/blissini/testfile` works as expected. Doesn't cron run commands as my user, if I create cronjobs via `crontab -e`?

Comment: cron does indeed have an environment and sets PATH (by default).  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56491/interactive-shell-with-environment-identical-to-cron/56503#56503

Comment: Removing the user solved it. Now I should ask, what's correct way to create and register a cronjob

Comment: @diegoaguilar You just did the correct way :)