# script runs under my user but fails under root and cron

Tags: shell-script, cron, monitoring, tor

Using some google and questions, I made this bash script

```
if [[ $(curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs) ]]; then
    curl -s https://hc-ping.com/abcdefgh &> /dev/null
 fi
```

curl uses my Tor replay's SOCKS to query check.torproject.org then grep searches it for Congratulations message, which if found means Tor is up. If it returns empty, it means either that something very odd is happening on my 9050 port or most probably that Tor is down.

If Congratulations is found, curl is used again to send a request to a hc-ping.com URL which stores monitoring on my Tor and internet availability.

Anyway, I saved it on a .sh and chmod +x it. if I run this file under my user it works. But if I run it with sudo I get a message `./availability-tor.sh: 1: ./availability-tor.sh: [[: not found`.

I added it to crontab -e executed under my user, and it fails because no request is sent to hc-ping.com.

My guess is that some difference in my bashrc makes it work, and whatever it is it's not used under sudo nor cron and make it fail. But I have no idea what it may be.

Comment: You're running the script with `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. Make sure that you have a proper `#!`-line pointing to the `bash` executable on your system.  Also, what is the purpose of `xargs` at the end of your pipeline, and why don't you use `grep -q` without the `[[ ... ]]`?   And that lone `cat`???  You `if` statement could probably be `if curl ... | grep -q Congrats; then ...`.

Comment: I believe you're on the right path; the usual suspect is an environment variable (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56503/117549). Looks like something along the lines of `https_proxy`, I would guess.

Comment: Thanks both for the help. I took this code somewhere and adapted it, I have no idea how if syntax is and what each command in pipes are doing. Indeed `#!/bin/bash` made it work under sudo, I'm waiting cron to run and see if it works! If u post as answer I can approve it.